# Disable auto-update Azure DevOps Extension Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server

in my company we're using Azure DevOps hosted on-premises. We have an internal team managing Azure DevOps Server and we need to disable the auto-update function for some (or even all) Azure extensions as SonarQube, because some new versions cause our build pipelines (they are nearly a hundred) failure.
How it is possible to disable auto-update function, so we can schedulate updates to have minimum impacts.
We prefer, if there is a way, to disable auto-update of DevOps extensions using Azure DevOps Server managing console.
Thank for anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, currently there is no option to control the auto-update Azure DevOps Extensions.

You could use "Request a feature" on the left side of Azure DevOps [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to open a new suggestion ticket.

Comment: Thank you @Ging-Yuan-MSFT
I think that it could be done using a stored procedure on the Azure DevOps supporting DB, but I do not know it's structure.

Comment: Sorry, there is no related information about this. You can try to create a suggestion ticket so that you can check with the product team.